# [PHP][Youtube api v3] retrieving the informations for a single video

Tags: php, api, video, youtube

I'm getting some trouble with the youtube api. I would like to retrieve the informations from a single video.

What I already got :

i can get videos from a specified playlist with all their informations (like the title, the description etc)

i get the id playlist from the Url :

```
$playlist = $_GET['pl'];
```

then i get the videos informations from the playlist :

```
$response = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('id,snippet,contentDetails', ['playlistId' => $playlist, 'maxResults' => '10']);
```

then i can easily get and show informations from those videos thanks to a foreach :

```
foreach($response['items'] as $video){
echo $video['contentDetails']['videoId']; 
echo $video['snippet']['title'];
echo substr($video['snippet']['description'], 0, 430);}
```

What I want :

now i just put the videoId into a link :

`href="index.php?requ=video&v=<?= $video['contentDetails']['videoId']; ?>&pl=<?= $playlist ?>"`

this way i can get the videoId into the other page in which i embed the video :

```
$vid = $_GET['v'];
<iframe height ="432" width="760"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $vid; ?>"></iframe>
```

but here comes the problem, i can't get any informations from this video, when i try like that :

```
$viewing = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet", ['id' => $vid]);
echo $viewing['snippet']['title'];
```

it returns me NULL

If someone can help me a bit, it would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution on my own.

as I want to retrieve information from a list of videos (even if in this case the list is composed of 1 element), I just had to use a foreach to retrieve like this :

```
<?php foreach($viewing['items'] as $view): ?>
                        <p><h3><?= $view['snippet']['title']; ?></h3></p>
                        <p><?= substr($view['snippet']['description'], 0, 430); ?></p>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope it can help